# what`s the difference between reference directly and using inflate

Tags: android, android-inflate

when i want to get a view object delared in xml,usually i have two method.R.id.view and inflate the view,so what`s the deference between them.
thanks in advance,i am a newbie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `setContentView()` your layout is inflated implicitly with all the views mentioned in the respected xml. When you inflate the view manually you do pretty the same, but explicitly. The difference is only in code you write.

Comment: but when i use R.id.view way,i can also change the attributes of the xml element and inflate can do the same.

Comment: Do you ask if inflating can do the same? Yes, inflate the view and obtain the appropriate object. You will be able to change the attributes then.

Comment: but how can i determine which to use?